# Flat file storage of database details

Tags: php, mysql, data-security

I need to store *mysql* database access details in a flat file format. I.e in a *.txt* and the details on separate lines. I can easily do this, but then there is a big security flaw that the details`.txt` file can easily be navigated to and read by anyone.

How can I make it so that this is not possible.

I tired to save the files as a .php but then it does not read the lines with the command.

```
$lines = file('details.php');
```

Comment: put that file out of root (WWW) so that no one can access it via URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your htaccess file you can add

```
<Files "database.txt">
    Order Allow,Deny
    Deny from all
</Files>
```

Which will prevent people accessing that file

Comment: Note that the htaccess file has to be in the same directory as your .txt file